# Redirect user to HTTPS URL not HTTP when he accesses the localhost URL "proj.test"

Tags: php, laravel

To access a localhost project using valet and https the URL is  "https://proj.test/". However, if the user accesses in the browser "proj.test" he is redirected to the HTTP URL not HTTPS.
Do you know what is necessary to configure so that if the user enters "proj.test" in the browser, he is redirected to the HTTPS URL not the HTTP one?
For now, for the user to be redirected to the HTTPS url he needs to write the full HTTPS url "https://proj.test/".

Comment: You should put that in your web server-config. Try searching for: _"How to redirect from http to https on [enter-the-name-of-your-webserver-here]"_.

Comment: In your virtual host or a .htaccess you could do the redirection.

Comment: Thanks, so is necessary to add a rule in the public/.htaccess file for that?

Comment: I recommend not adding it to .htaccess since this is most likely in your VCS repo and used for development.  Just add it to your virtualhost configuration on the production web server.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain better that about add in the virtualbox configuration on the production server? Im just testing on localhost.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-i-can-force-all-my-routes-to-be-https-not-http?page=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# force ssl
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Note that this should be your first rewrite rule.